# where does the acc argument come from in mosquitto-go-auth jwt backend checkAcl function?

Tags: authentication, mqtt, mosquitto

I want to use mosquitto-go-auth plugin to enable some custom authentication/authorization logic.

The mosquitto-go-auth backend I chose is jwt in js mode (https://github.com/iegomez/mosquitto-go-auth#js-mode).

One of the requirements is that the ACL can be configured dynamically based on the topic and the username field in the jwt claims.

As per the document, when using jwt backend in js mode, we can specify a jwt_js_acl_script and some logic can be put in it. Below is an example of the script mentioned in mosquitto-go-auth plugin repository:

[image]

As you can see, an argument called 'acc' is passed to the function and it looks like it has something to do with the following mosquitto ACL.

```
#define MOSQ_ACL_NONE 0x00
#define MOSQ_ACL_READ 0x01
#define MOSQ_ACL_WRITE 0x02
#define MOSQ_ACL_SUBSCRIBE 0x04
```

I am just wondering where does the checkAcl function get the value of acc? Does it need to be defined somewhere?

In addition, since this function has a return value of boolean type, how can I set a custom ACL based on username and topic?

For example, in the checkAcl function, I would like to give the user the "subscribe" or "read" access to topic topic/${username}/#

Comment: The [mosquitto docs](https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto_plugin-h.html#mosquitto_auth_acl_check) might help you understand this. Mosquitto calls `mosquitto_auth_acl_check` (which will end up calling your `checkAcl`) when it needs to confirm access to a topic. The source of `mosquitto-go-auth` is relatively easy to follow - see [here](https://github.com/iegomez/mosquitto-go-auth/blob/master/auth-plugin.c#L131) and [here](https://github.com/iegomez/mosquitto-go-auth/blob/ea7214a10a3905080287482f6058a9762e838518/backends/backends.go#L452).

Comment: Thanks @Brits. It makes sense to me now.